# Why is the ObjectStateFormatter class in the System.Web.UI namespace?

Tags: .net, namespaces, system.web

Very straight forward question. As far as I can see from the MSDN page, it seems to be all about serialization and nothing to do with Web!

MSDN: [ObjectStateFormatter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.objectstateformatter.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpy, it is quite tightly related to [`PageStatePersister`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pagestatepersister.aspx) and a few other web assets like [`Triplet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.triplet.aspx) (which I confess I've never heard of before).

You are right in that *fundamentally* that class has little directly to do with web, but I can see why it would be tempting to leave it with it's siblings (with which it is designed to be used). Ultimately, though.... meh. Naming stuff (and I'll include namespaces in that) is hard...

Comment: I'd never heard of it either. Thanks for the interesting answer! Now I'll have to post a question about the Triplet class too. It's [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702396/what-is-the-triplet-class-used-for-is-it-related-to-tuples)