# What is the Triplet class used for? Is it related to Tuples?

Tags: c#, asp.net, tuples

So I just learnt about the [`Triplet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.triplet.aspx) class. I have no experience with ASP.NET, only the core .NET Framework.

Can someone explain to me where/why the Triplet class exists? Is it like a Tuple?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's pretty much like Tuple from .NET 4.0, but dates back to .NET 1.0 and ASP.NET 1.0 in particular. It's primarily used in [ViewState serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx):

> The Page class contains a `SavePageViewState()`, which is invoked during the page life cycle's save view state stage. The `SavePageViewState()` method starts by creating a `Triplet` that contains the following three items:
>
> 1. The page's hash code. This hash code is used to ensure that the view state hasn't been  #tampered with between postbacks. We'll talk more about view state hashing in the "View State and Security Implications" section.
> 2. The collective view state of the `Page`'s control hierarchy.
> 3. An `ArrayList` of controls in the control hierarchy that need to be explicitly invoked by the page class during the raise postback event stage of the life cycle.

There's also its' younger brother called [`Pair`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pair.aspx).

There's absolutely no reason you should even bother about these classes or else an unholy untyped mess will ensue.

Comment: +1 "it's pretty much like Tuple" - except that Triplet is weakly-typed, Tuple uses generics and is strongly typed. I agree you should ignore unless developing ASP.NET custom controls that serialize to ViewState.

Comment: @Joe Hence my snarky comment on untyped mess.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and informed answer!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it's got one more object than a Pair.  You use it when you need to return exactly three items.

C# and Java are different from Python, which will convert multiple return values into a tuple.

A Triple does sound like a tuple to me - one that has exactly three items.