# Why are Pair and Triplet class System.Web.UI (can I use them in Console app)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, collections, tuples

Bumped into ancient .NET [Pair Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pair%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [Triplet Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.triplet.aspx)

Why are they in System.Web.UI namespace?
Can I use them in desktop (Windows Forms) or console app?

Update:
There was a similar question [What is the Triplet class used for? Is it related to Tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702396/what-is-the-triplet-class-used-for-is-it-related-to-tuples?rq=1)
I didn't mix it into the question in order to avoid making this question the duplicate

**Update2:**
The main purpose of this question is to understand the principles and rationale of partitioning classes into namespaces in .NET framework, i.e. to avoid situations of finding something in separate and unexpected places (of documentation and namespaces.

Comment: why don't you write it yourself the Pair class looks pretty easy to implement

Comment: @ MUG4N, have you read my Update2? It is not about how to re-use or implement but what to expect from, how to follow and have grasps of .NET framework structuring (architecture and design principles) of .NET and respectively documentation on it, finding the structurally common artefacts in completely disparate and UNEXPECTED places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, you can**, ff you don't mind adding a reference to `System.Web.UI`...

It is really weird, they belonging there, but it's implementation it so easy you can design your own, and adding functionality as you go.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you could use `System.Tuple<T1, T2, T...>`